# Android XML Drawable Windows Phone 8 Equivalent

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, android-xml, android-drawable, windows-phone-8-sdk

I have an Android app that uses a lot of XML drawables (shapes, layer lists, and state list), and I want to port this app to Windows Phone 8. Is there an equivalent to XML drawables (specifically the types I list above) in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For layer lists and state list i think the equivalent is VisualStates but they are not so similar. [Define different visual states for a control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735539%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), You can find many different examples to VisualState's [here](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP8/Themes/Generic.xaml) inside a VisualState you gave different properties different values (such as different Image to background of a button when pressed) or define animations.

For shapes there are [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207026%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that you can define in your xaml file. If you want to define a gradient should look at [brushes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206969%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).